# How to perform one time action on first login using ASP.NET MVC5 Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, windows-authentication

I am creating web application using ASP.NET MVC5 framework with 'windows authentication' - i.e. I am creating an intranet application authenticating users against active directory.

When new user is defined in company's active directory, I'd need to catch his first login and redirect him onto profile page, where user is prompted to fill some info.

I am able to catch user's first login by simple look into the database, if the user has here his own record in some table. If not, the user is here first time and I can create him such record.

Here comes the deal - after extensive searching through possibilities it seems the only "reasonable" way how to do it is via custom AuthenticationFilter - specifically to put the DB check logic into

```
OnAuthenticationChallenge(AuthenticationChallengeContext filterContext)
```

method.

The reason why I put "reasonable" into the quotes is that on one hand, this approach fits into the MVC philosophy - by which I mean that it is not some 'hack' approach.

On the other hand - since I am using windows authentication, there is effectively no Login action in any controller. User can type whatever 'www.mysite.com/controller/action' url and if not logged in, there is no redirect to login page, the windows security box just appears prompting for credentials. Which means that I have to register my custom authentication filter globally to cover all controller/action patterns. That would mean that the DB check would be performed each and every request - I don't like this. I am not sure how much performance hit this could make, but also it doesn't seem right from design point of view.

The last thing I've tried was to use my authentication filter to catch 'unauthenticated' users and redirect them to some 'Login' action - but here I found that the windows security box is appearing before even the authentication filter is fired, so technically my custom authentication filter never catches an unauthenticated user.

So my question is - is there a better approach how to step in the logging process with one time action? Or I can use what I have - i.e. globally registered authentication filter performing DB check every request ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you use session state to track whether you have already performed this action for the user?  This would be my approach but we are ok with and regularly use session state, and not everyone does.

Comment: @stephen.vakil: Session is definitely one way to go. I was trying to find something like event fired after user's successful login - to avoid performing that check on each request - but apparently no event like this does exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have some working solution for this.

The problem:

MVC5 APS.NET intranet application using windows authentication. After successful login against active directory we want to find out if the user is here for the first time and if so, create him record in application database.

The solution:

Since I am at the end of the day interested only in authenticated and authorized users I've created a **globally registered action filter** i.e. filter which will be applied to every single controller/action combination after successful authentication/authorization.

Inside this filter I am checking if the current **session** has flag **IsNewSession** set to true. If so, I am performing that check against application DB. That way even if the action filter is invoked each request I am doing roundtrip into database only once - during user's first request.

The implementation:

```
public class DbCheckFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private AppDbContext db = new AppDbContext();

    //we are overriding OnActionExecuting method since this one
    //is executed prior the controller action method itself
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //is this a new session
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session.IsNewSession)
        {
            //we are storing users in db based on their active directory
            //Guid - therefore we need to get 'UserPrincipal' object
            //instead of 'WindowsPrincipal' provided by filterContext
            using (var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
            {
                var principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);

                if (principal != null)
                {
                    //finally we perform the DB check itself
                    if (!CreateUserInDbIfNew(principal.Guid.Value, principal.DisplayName))
                    {
                        filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
                }
            }
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for. Your db check will only happen once at this point. You can add this method to your `Global.asax` like so, which works with Windows Auth once authorized...

```
protected void Application_AuthorizeRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do your check here
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: I believe this would still be getting called for each request.

Comment: I would say too, this one would be executed during each request. But thanks for mentioning it - I had at least chance to learn something about global.asax :) anyway at the end I've decided to put the logic into application filter since here I know 100% user is authenticated/authorized and I can use session with no problems - in global.asax you have to wait for specific event before the session is available.