# How to prevent ClaimsTransformerService from running multiple times per user login?

Tags: c#, .net, api, authentication, authorization

I'm using windows authentication and *IClaimsTransformation* in my Blazor ServerApp (.NET 6.0)

I don't know why the `ClaimsTransformerService` runs 4 times per user login or per page refresh. Is there any way to prevent this?

The following code basically tries to check if a username is available in a database and if it is, record the login event in another table.

```
namespace MyServerApp.Services
{
    public class ClaimsTransformerService : IClaimsTransformation
    {
        private IUserService _userService;
        private ILoginRecordService _loginRecordService;

        public ClaimsTransformerService(IUserService userService, ILoginRecordService loginRecordService)
        {
            _userService = userService;
            _loginRecordService = loginRecordService;
        }

        public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
        {
            var user = await _userService.GetUser(principal.Identity.Name.ToLower());

            ((ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity).AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "MyUser"));

            return principal;
        }
    }
}
```

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30534994/how-to-perform-one-time-action-on-first-login-using-asp-net-mvc5-windows-authent) thread and it didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

The Microsoft documentation states that the TransformAsync() method may get called multiple times. From the docs:

> The IClaimsTransformation interface can be used to add extra claims to the  ClaimsPrincipal class. The interface requires a single method TransformAsync. This method might get called multiple times. Only add a new claim if it does not already exist in the ClaimsPrincipal. A ClaimsIdentity is created to add the new claims and this can be added to the ClaimsPrincipal.

So you should write your AsyncMethod defensively and only add claims if they do not already exist:

```
public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
{
    if (!principal.HasClaim(claim => claim.Type == ClaimTypes.Role && claim.Value == "MyUser"))
    {
        var user = await _userService.GetUser(principal.Identity.Name.ToLower());
        ((ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity).AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "MyUser"));

    }
    return principal;
}
```